# Wildcard for SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Host in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache

I want to restrict access to a directory using SetEnvIfNoCase and a wildcard for Remote_Host. For example, I'd like to permit access to the directory for any client requesting the directory from *.example.com.

(In practice, I'm going to use it to restrict access of this directory to requests from googlebot.com, etc.)

What I have in my htaccess does not work and I believe it is because of an improperly formatted wildcard:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Host ^(.*).example.com$ OK_friend

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=OK_friend
```

I have tried changing the Remote_Host to Remote_Addr and putting my IP address, and everything works fine. I just can't seem to get this to work for a wildcard on the remote hostname.

Comment: After some debugging, I found this works only if the remote hostname is written in the "Allow from" line ... i.e. "Allow from example.com" works but the `SetEnvIfNoCase` line doesn't capture the remote hostname, for some reason that I do not understand.

Comment: I have rephrased my problem and posted it over here: http://serverfault.com/questions/566646/allow-from-remote-hostname-works-but-not-when-using-setenvif-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try non-greedy by adding a "?" and escape your "." since it is a RegEx metacharacter:

```
^(.*?)\.example\.com$
```

Or you can simplify it further if you're just running a check without capturing any groups:

```
^.*?\.example\.com$
```

Comment: This isn't working. I wonder if it's server related. I checked and confirmed that my server has authz_host_module enabled. Even without the wildcard, when I input my entire client hostname into htaccess, I cannot access this directory. Do you know a simple way to check if apache is setup for SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Host to work properly?